# Get Text from XML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've got a somewhat large XML document in my browser and within that document exists some elements with URLs. There are 1,000 of them, to be exact. I need those URLs in a new text document. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use JavaScript, jQuery or anything other language in the console to get that text out to the console (again, in the browser) where I can copy and paste the results to a new text file.

For example:

```
...
  <U>
    http://someURL.org/somesearch.jsp?R=somefilename&someOtherStuff
  </U>
...
```

I would like to get the URL (all 1,000) of them out of the page by any means. If I could get them output to a .txt file, that would be even better. I could very well manually do that with a click of the mouse, but then I won't learn any cool new tricks.

Any help that you can provide would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do this on the clientside? If you have an XML file and you're trying to extract pieces of it, use an editor or the serverside to parse the XML and get what you want ?

Comment: If you know the path to the URL elements (I'm assuming it will be a similar/same path for all of them) then jQuery is perfect for this.  Can you show more of the xml?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show too much of the XML as it contains proprietary information.

Comment: adeneo, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not very proficient with this type of task.

Comment: Just show us the structure - you can take any data out that's not relevant to the question.  What @adeneo means, is if you're creating the xml file yourself on your server, then this should be done *before* sending it, rather than after.

Comment: You're right Archer. I went ahead and got the structure and replaced anything that could be construed as proprietary. http://pastebin.com/WXfmeGAv

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/QpfzF/

```
var data = '<doc><U>url1</U><U>url2</U><U>url3</U><doc>', //xml string
    memo = $("#memo"), //textarea
    text = [];

$(data) //wrap xml with jQuery
       .find("U") //find all U tags
       .text(function(_, val){ //extract text from all U nodes
           text.push(val); //dump text to array.
        });

console.log(text.join("\n"); //out to console
memo.val(text.join("\n")); //or to a textarea
```

Comment: You can use `console.log(text)`; the browser will then preserve the data structure.